# C++: Matriz elevada a potencia cuadrada

Tags: c++

Quiero realizar un programa que en base a una matriz cuadrada (mismo numero de filas y columnas) calcule la potencia cuadrada de esa matriz.

Codigo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int fila,columna,i,j;

cout<<"Ingrese numero de filas: ";
cin>>fila;
cout<<"\n";
cout<<"Ingrese numero de columnas: ";
cin>>columna;

if(fila==columna){


int matriz[fila][columna];

for(i=0;i<fila;i++){
    for(j=0;j<columna;j++){
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"Ingrese numero para la posicion ["<<i<<"] - ["<<j<<"] ";
        cin>>matriz[i][j];
        }
    }

        }

else{
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"Su matriz no es cuadrada";
}

return 0;
system("pause");

}
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Como podría calcular la potencia cuadrada de una matriz MXN?
Por lo que tengo entendido para obtener la potencia de una matriz se debe multiplicar la matriz por sí misma 'n' veces.
Pero aun no tengo entendido los pasos que conlleva el método para su solución en si.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tu matriz está mal.

Para empezar tienes un gran fallo en tu programa al crear la matriz:

```
int matriz[fila][columna];
```

En C++ los tamaños de las formaciones<sup>1</sup> deben ser valores conocidos en tiempo de compilación, pero en tu caso `fila` y `columna` son conocidos en tiempo de ejecución. Si te funciona será porque tu compilador ofrece esa posibilidad como extensión pero otros compiladores rechazarían ese código o tu mismo compilador podría decidir dejar de dar soporte a esa extensión. Lee [estas preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+vla) para saber más del tema.

También tienes un error conceptual: si quieres matrices cuadradas ¿para qué pides tanto ancho como alto? Pide sólo el lado y úsalo para hacer que la matriz sea cuadrada por diseño:

#### Tu matriz debería ser así.

```
int *matriz = new int[lado * lado];
```

Ésta es la manera correcta de crear una matriz cuyo tamaño es conocido en tiempo de ejecución; por desgracia C++ no ofrece manera de crear formaciones bidimensionales mediante el operador `new`, así que lo que creamos es una formación de una dimensión pero que trataremos como si fuese de dos dimensiones con simple aritmética de punteros.

#### De 1D a 2D.

Teniendo una matriz cuadrada bidimensional almacenada en una formación de una dimensión, para obtener el elemento de la fila `y` y columna `x` deberíamos calcular su posición de la siguiente manera:

> Índice del elemento = (y * lado) + x

Una función auxiliar puede ser útil:

```
int &elemento(int *&matriz_cuadrada, int lado, int x, int y) {
    return matriz_cuadrada[(y * lado) + x];
}
```

#### Cuadrado.

Será necesaria una matriz auxiliar para realizar la operación ya que se necesita consultar las celdas originales. Por otro lado, dado que la [multiplicación de matrices](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicaci%C3%B3n_de_matrices) implica sumar los productos de filas y columnas, sería útil tener unas funciones auxiliares que hagan dicha operación:

```
int opera_fila(int *&matriz_cuadrada, int fila, int lado) {
    int resultado{};
    for (int x = 0; x < lado; ++x)
    {
        auto valor = elemento(matriz_cuadrada, lado, x, fila);
        resultado += (valor * valor);
    }
    return resultado;
}

int opera_columna(int *&matriz_cuadrada, int columna, int lado) {
    int resultado{};
    for (int y = 0; y < lado; ++y)
    {
        auto valor = elemento(matriz_cuadrada, lado, columna, y);
        resultado += (valor * valor);
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Y finalmente la función podría parecerse a:

```
void cuadrado(int *&matriz_cuadrada, int lado) {
    int *matriz = new int[lado * lado];

    for (int y = 0; y < lado; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < lado; ++x)
        {
            elemento(matriz, lado, x, y) = opera_fila(matriz_cuadrada, y, lado) + opera_columna(matriz_cuadrada, x, lado);
        }
    }

    std::copy(matriz, matriz + (lado * lado), matriz_cuadrada);
    delete[] matriz;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jnaQ9i34CkF8oKKo)</kbd>, te queda como ejercicio corregirlo.

Answer (score 0):

El cuadrado de una matriz se calcula a base de multiplicar para cada `valor[i][j]` los valores de la `fila[i]` y `columna[j]` entre si y finalmente sumarlos.
Basicamente es un producto de matrices pero con la misma matriz.

```
EJEMPLO cuadrado de una matriz 2x2

|2 2|*|2 2|=|8 6|
|2 1| |2 1| |6 5|

posición (0,0) = 2*2 + 2*2 = 8, posición (0,1) = 2*2 + 2*1 = 6
posición (1,0) = 2*2 + 1*2 = 6, posición (1,1) = 2*2 + 1*1 = 5
```

Una vez comprendido esto veamos para una matriz MxM, ya que es cuadrada.

```
Matriz MxM

[0,0][0,1][0,2]..[0,M]
[1,0][1,1][1,2]..[1,M]
[2,0][2,1][2,2]..[2,M]
 ...  ...  ... .. ...
[M,0][M,1][M,2]..[M,M]
```

Para obtener la nueva matriz resultado se tendrá que recorrer cada posición de la matriz MxM e ir calculando el valor que se almacenará en esa misma posición en la matriz resultado.

Para el caso de la posicion `matriz[0][2]`:

```
  matriz[0][0]    matriz[0][1]    matriz[0][2] ...   matriz[0][M]
x matriz[0][2]  x matriz[1][2]  x matriz[2][2] ... x matriz[M][2]
-------------  -------------  --------------    -------------
 producto_0  +  producto_1  +  producto_2     +  producto_M  = matrizResult[0][2]
```

A estas alturas el patrón ya se puede intuir, pero intentaré mostrarlo.

Recorremos la matriz con bucles de la forma `matriz[i][j]` donde `i` y `j` tomarán valores de `0` al valor indicado por `fila` o `columna`.

Substituyendo en el caso anterior para una posición `matriz[i][j]`:

```
  matriz[i][0]    matriz[i][1]    matriz[i][2] ...   matriz[i][M]
x matriz[0][j]  x matriz[1][j]  x matriz[2][j] ... x matriz[M][j]
-------------  -------------  --------------    -------------
 producto_0  +  producto_1  +  producto_2     +  producto_M  = matrizResult[i][j]
```

Puede verse como hay similitud a la hora de calcular el producto de cada término y que se sigue una serie que se incrementa de `0` a `M` siendo `M`  conocida ya que es el tamaño de la matriz `M == fila == columna`, por lo que podemos simplificar el cálculo haciendo uso de un nuevo bucle donde una variable `k` tomará los valores de `0` al valor indicado por `fila` o `columna` y finalmente el resultado sería igual al sumatorio de todos los productos.

```
matrizResult[i][j] += matriz[i][k] * matriz[k][j]
```

Comment: La indexación con comas en el corchete (`matrizResult[i,j]`) es un disparate en C++, no funciona.

Comment: Ya, en ningún momento he puesto código, pretendía dar una explicación, igual confunde más que ayudar... humm

Comment: La explicación de cómo se multiplican matrices es correcta (que yo sepa), no es correcto cómo lo has puesto en pseudo-código, es sólo una cuestión de estilo pero si cambias `matrizResult[i,j]` por `matrizResult[i][j]`: mucho mejor.